# I wants to add a new column based on dates in my csv file using python or pandas

Tags: python

I need to add a new column called national holidays to my current csv file based on this pic[national holidays that i want to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcpfk.png) could anyone offer me some help[current csv file i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWvCd.png)

Comment: show the code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to do this is using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

First, install pandas using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/):

```
pip install pandas
```

Then, create a new dataframe with `read_csv()` as an argument (reads csv from the current filepath):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(read_csv('filename.csv'))
```

Finally, you can add column with the following command:

```
pd['column_name'] = data
```

Note that `data` can be a list or any single variable. If you do not provide a list as an argument all the values in the column will be the same as the variable provided.

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_create_column_using_conditional.html)